# Fallback font for specific face

Tags: org-mode, faces, fonts, emacs-daemon

I'm trying to set a fallback font for `variable-pitch` face.

More specifically, my current setup is:

- Default font set to JuliaMono with size 15 via `(set-frame-font "JuliaMono 15" nil t)`.
- Fallback font for hangul (Korean) via `(set-fontset-font t 'hangul (font-spec :name "D2Coding"))`.
- Variable pitch face set to EB Garamond with size 19 via `(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil :font "EB Garamond" :height 190)`.

Is there a way to specifically add a new font used for Korean for variable pitch face (I'm trying to use Noto Serif CJK KR)?
https://idiocy.org/emacs-fonts-and-fontsets.html only points to setting fallback fonts for different languages, and not face-specific.

---

**Edit**
I spent the whole afternoon trying this--it is driving me mad!

I'm setting the default fonts following [this](https://archive.casouri.cat/note/2021/fontset/index.html) and [this](https://idiocy.org/emacs-fonts-and-fontsets.html):

```
(add-to-list 'after-make-frame-functions #'set-default-fonts)
(defun set-default-fonts (_)
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "JuliaMono 15")
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'hangul (font-spec :family "D2Coding"))
  (setq face-font-rescale-alist '(("D2Coding" . 1.2))))
```

Rescaling "D2Coding" is to [make a single monospaced Korean letter correspond to two monospaced alphabets](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/align-columns-in-org-mode-with-korean-letters/72270#72270).
The `(add-to-list ...)` part is to make it work with `emacs --daemon`.

I'm trying to use mixed-pitch package to achieve variable pitch mode default in Org mode, so:

```
(use-package mixed-pitch
  :ensure t
  :hook
  (org-mode . mixed-pitch-mode)
  :config
  (setq mixed-pitch-set-height t)
  (set-face-attribute
   'variable-pitch nil :font "fontset-myvariable"))
```

where the custom fontset `"fontset-myvariable"` is set via:

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name
  (font-spec :family "EB Garamond"
         :size 19
         :registry "fontset-myvariable")))
(set-fontset-font
 "fontset-myvariable"
 'hangul (font-spec :family "Noto Serif CJK KR" :size 19))
```

With this, (EB Garamond in variable pitch face + English) & (D2Coding in fixed with + Korean) works great, but (variable pitch face + Korean) is in D2Coding not Noto Serif CJK KR.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own fontset with EB Garamond as the default font and Noto Serif CJK KR as the `hangul` font, and then assign that to the `:font` attribute of `variable-pitch`.

According to [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html):

```
‘:font’
     The font used to display the face.  Its value should be a font
     object or a fontset.  [...]
```

What strangely seems to work for me is setting both `:font` and `:fonset`:

```lisp
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name
  (font-spec :family "EB Garamond"
             :size 19
             :registry "fontset-variable")))

(set-fontset-font "fontset-variable" 'hangul
                  (font-spec :family "Noto Serif CJK KR"
                             :size 19
                             :registry "iso10646-1"))

(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil
                    :font "fontset-variable" :fontset "fontset-variable")
```

My Emacs is:

```
GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0, NS appkit-2113.50 Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)) of 2022-07-25
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I can't make Noto Serif CJK KR as the `hangul` font--it only shows in D2Coding. I updated the post to show my setup...

Comment: What happens if you use `(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil :fontset "fontset-myvariable")` (i.e., `:fontset` instead of `:font`)?

Comment: Unfortunately, EB Garamond won't show up as well with `:fontset`.

Comment: The problem even happens when I try to `set-fontset-font` to other languages, e.g., `'greek`. So basically the font is stuck with the one created with `(create-fontset-... (font-xlfd-name (font-spec ...)`.

Comment: Please try setting both `:font` and `:fontset`, as per my edit.

Comment: Thank you the help. However, it doesn't seem to work with your edit for me---I was using Emacs 28, and I just updated to Emacs 29.0.50 (https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus). I think it has something to do with setting a default Korean font (D2Coding), since it is used even when I set "Noto Serif CJK KR" as the only `create-fontset-from-fontset-spec`.

Comment: Or perhaps `mixed-pitch` is messing around..?